# Checked Radio Buttons ID using Jquery change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a set of radio buttons which I'd like to find the selected radio buttons ID using jQuery.

That is my set of Radio Buttons, With the following jQueryCode - I'm receiving an 'Undefined' alert whenever I change radio buttons.

```js
$("#radios").on("change", function() {
    myID = $("#radios").nextAll(":radio:checked").first().attr('id');
    alert(myID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radios">
   <input id="option1" name="options" type="radio" checked>
   <label value="test" for="option1">X-01</label>
   <input id="option2" name="options" type="radio">
   <label for="option2">X-02</label>
   <input id="option3" name="options" type="radio">
   <label for="option3">X-03</label>
   <input id="option4" name="options" type="radio">
   <label for="option4">M-01</label>
   <input id="option5" name="options" type="radio">
   <label for="option5">M-02</label>
   <input id="option6" name="options" type="radio">
   <label for="option6">M-04</label>
   <input id="option7" name="options" type="radio">
   <label for="option7">L-01</label>
   <input id="option8" name="options" type="radio">
   <label for="option8">L-02</label>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As radio buttons are children of `#radios` div, You need to use [`$.fn.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

*Code*, Also bind change event with radio buttons

```
$( "#radios input:radio" ).on( "change", function() {
   myID = $("#radios").find(":radio:checked").first().attr('id');
   alert(myID);
});
```

Note: You can also use [`$.fn.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/), However The `.children()` method differs from `.find()`.

Comment: Hey, 
This worked however I've ran into one problem. Since I'm using this Jquery plugin [link](http://rubentd.com/radios-to-slider), the function only runs when the TEXT is clicked and not when the radio button is clicked.

Comment: The standard $("#radios") works with both the button and the text, but when adding the 'input:radio' it breaks. Any tips?

Comment: I've gotten it working using the following snippet: 
$("#radios").on("change", function () {
    myID = $("#radios").find(":radio:checked").first().attr('id');
    //                  ^^^^
    alert(myID);
});

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `find` method to get the `radio`.

```
$("#radios").on("change", function () {
    myID = $("#radios").find(":radio:checked").first().attr('id');
    //                  ^^^^
    alert(myID);
});
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/575Lycoj/

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1) Attach the change event to input element rather than attaching to div with id `#radios`

2) and then find checked element in it.
:

```
$( "#radios input" ).on( "change", function() {
   myID = $("#radios :radio:checked").first().attr('id');
   alert(myID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "#radios" ).on( "change", function() {
myID = $(this).find(":radio:checked").first().attr('id');
  alert(myID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radios">
        <input id="option1" name="options" type="radio" checked>
        <label value="test" for="option1">X-01</label>

        <input id="option2" name="options" type="radio">
        <label for="option2">X-02</label>

        <input id="option3" name="options" type="radio">
        <label for="option3">X-03</label>

        <input id="option4" name="options" type="radio">
        <label for="option4">M-01</label>

        <input id="option5" name="options" type="radio">
        <label for="option5">M-02</label>

        <input id="option6" name="options" type="radio">
        <label for="option6">M-04</label>
        
        <input id="option7" name="options" type="radio">
        <label for="option7">L-01</label>
        
        <input id="option8" name="options" type="radio">
        <label for="option8">L-02</label>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `event` on the `input`s and get the `id` of the checked radio. Try with -

```
$( "#radios input" ).on( "change", function() {
myID = $("#radios input:radio:checked").attr('id');
  alert(myID);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/twt77t49/)

Answer (score 0):

While the change event works due to bubbling, it would be nicer to bind the event to elements which actually fire the change event:

```
$("#radios").on("change", 'input', function() {
  var myID = $("#radios input").filter(":radio:checked").first().attr('id');
  alert(myID);
});
```